# QLineEdit being deleted after a couple of screens

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm using a QLineEdit and then needing to refer to it after 2 screens in PyQt. However I consistently keep getting this error when I refer to it

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[filename]", line 227, in passwordmissing2ndscreenverify
    P1=self.entrypasswordmissingscreen1.text()
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted`

This is my first time using Qt to create complex programs that refer to things from several screens before so if anyone can help that'll be appreciated.

Heres the code for that section as well:

```
def passwordmissing1stscreen(self):
    #layouts
    self.mainLayout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.secondaryLayout=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

    #Labels
    self.passwordMissing1stScreenlabel= QtWidgets.QLabel("Please enter the new password")

    #buttons
    self.cancelbutton=QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel", self)
    self.okButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton("OK", self)
    #input
    self.entrypasswordmissingscreen1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    P1 = self.entrypasswordmissingscreen1.text()
    #conections
    self.cancelbutton.clicked.connect(self.exit)
    self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.passwordmissing2ndscreen)

    #add to layouts
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.passwordMissing1stScreenlabel)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.entrypasswordmissingscreen1)
    self.secondaryLayout.addWidget(self.okButton)
    self.secondaryLayout.addWidget(self.cancelbutton)
    self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.secondaryLayout)


    #display screen#
    self.mainViewWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.mainViewWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.mainViewWidget)



def passwordmissing2ndscreen(self):
    #layouts
    self.mainLayout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.secondaryLayout=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

    #Labels
    self.passwordMissing2ndScreenlabel= QtWidgets.QLabel("Please enter the new password again")

    #buttons
    self.cancelbutton=QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel", self)
    self.okButton=QtWidgets.QPushButton("OK", self)

    #input
    self.entrypasswordmissingscreen2=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()


    #add to layouts
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.passwordMissing2ndScreenlabel)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.entrypasswordmissingscreen2)
    self.secondaryLayout.addWidget(self.okButton)
    self.secondaryLayout.addWidget(self.cancelbutton)
    self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.secondaryLayout)
    #conections
    self.cancelbutton.clicked.connect(self.exit)
    self.okButton.clicked.connect(self.passwordmissing2ndscreenverify)

    #display screen#
    self.mainViewWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.mainViewWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.mainViewWidget)

def passwordmissing2ndscreenverify(self):
    P1=self.entrypasswordmissingscreen1.text()
    P2=self.entrypasswordmissingscreen2.text()
    print (P1)
    print (P2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some discussions with friends and other fellow programmers we came across a solution that works perfectly instead of having `P1 = self.entrypasswordmissingscreen1.text()` in passwordmissing1stscreen instead put `self.P1.entrypasswordmissingscreen1.text()` in passwordmissing2ndscreen and have all references to `P1` changed to `self.P1`